# How to install the acr112_pcsc driver?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I follow on this file 
https://github.com/episage/SharpNFC/blob/master/README.md

When I type

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

I get

```
 selected_drivers:
acr112_pcsc no
```

how to install that?

and when i press

```
./configure --disable-libudev --enable-libusb
```

i get `libudev support : no`

but why? i install `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev`

Comment: Are you able to download `libnfc` .?

Comment: the url from your guide is 404 Not Found, could you add the url from the sources?

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros that work    GAD3R i dont get you

Comment: `wget https://libnfc.googlecode.com/files/libnfc-1.7.0.tar.bz2`
 from the README shows `ERROR: 404 Not Found` from where are you getting the source code?

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros wget https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/releases/download/libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc-1.7.1.tar.bz2

Comment: go to libnfc direcotry and instead of `./configure --prefix=/usr` run `./install-sh`

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific program you need to do the following:

`cd to your directory`

then

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-drivers='acr122_usb,acr122s,arygon,pn532_i2c,pn532_spi,pn532_uart,pn53x_usb,acr122_pcsc'
```

You will need to have installed `libpcsclite` to compile it.

After all the process is done, you simply run

`make && make install`

if you need help installing libpcsclite you can follow this [site](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/pcsclite.html)

PS. if you need more specific info `./configure --help` is a good starting point, and you can also read the INSTALL archive that comes with the tarball

Edit:

I'd suggest you to try it first the simple way... I can see that compilation and building is quite new for you, libudev is part from systemd and you'd probably don't need to erase it from your system. On the other hand, if you really need to use libusb, you'll need to fill the dependencies that pop up during compilation.

Comment: i realy need libusb and i install libusb-dev  what can i do  fot libudev?

Comment: If you have already installed them and there is no conflict you can add `--disable-libudev --enable-libusb` to the `./configure ...` command that I gave you and see what happens

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-drivers='acr122_usb,acr122s,arygon,pn532_i2c,pn532_spi,pn532_uart,pn53x_usb,acr122_pcsc' --disable-libudev --enable-libusb `   unrecognize option

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/usr --with-drivers='acr122_usb,acr122s,arygon,pn532_i2c,pn532_spi,pn532_uart,pn53x_usb,acr122_pcsc' --disable-libudev --enable-libusb-win32`?

Comment: I will try thank! but is it important or only that only not show the peoblem of libudev ?

Comment: well, your source code comes with a win32 libusb directory, so this options enables the code that is on it, usually when you want to compile something you'll need to read the README or INSTALL that comes with the source, I can't tell you exactly because I've never used that program before, good luck with that